# show quickest answer in microtime() for game score

Tags: php, datetime

When saving game questions I need to know what is the quickest time that a visitor gives the right answer to a question. The answer + time are saved into a table.

What is the best way to save within milliseconds, what fieldtype do I need, how can I see what is the quickest answer on a day?

Now I use date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time()), but that is not specific enough.
With microtime() I get something like this:

0.60388700 1467372627

0.38858700 1467372850

In BIGINT I get 1467375240.7142,  1467375398.7361

But I have to see on a day which time is the quickest.

Is there someone of you who can help me getting the right fieldtype and result query.
I appreciate it.

Comment: `BIGINT`? don't use float as that is an inprecise value (it floats on digital waves)

Comment: You could have `unsigned` as well if you aren't planning on storing negative numbers...

Comment: [This post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13022/80979) makes a good case for using the `DECIMAL` format as it can take upto 64 digits, apparently.

Comment: Here is my solution: date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . substr(microtime(), 1, 7)  Field BIGINT(20). Works fine.